# ¿Cómo guardar lista de tareas en MySQL?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, insert

Tengo dos dudas:

Una de ellas consiste en como dejar en espera un artículo de una lista,
por ejemplo, si tengo que registrar algo que haré, como comprar cereal, quiero que se guarde; para eso haría un *insert* en *mysql*; mi tabla se llama *cheak* y solo tiene un campo que es el de la lista.

Entonces quiero que este código de *checklist* me deje en espera cuando registro alguna tarea y después, cuando la marco, ya que para ello utilizaría *javascript*.

```js
// Create a "close" button and append it to each list item
    var myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
      var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
      var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
      span.className = "close";
      span.appendChild(txt);
      myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
    }
    
    // Click on a close button to hide the current list item
    var close = document.getElementsByClassName("close");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
      close[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
    
    // Add a "checked" symbol when clicking on a list item
    var list = document.querySelector('ul');
    list.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
      if (ev.target.tagName === 'LI') {
        ev.target.classList.toggle('checked');
      }
    }, false);

// Create a new list item when clicking on the "Add" button
function newElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var inputValue = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
  var t = document.createTextNode(inputValue);
  li.appendChild(t);
  if (inputValue === '') {
    alert("You must writ!");
  } else {
    document.getElementById("myUL").appendChild(li);
  }
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "";

  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var txt = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.className = "close";
  span.appendChild(txt);
  li.appendChild(span);

  for (i = 0; i < close.length; i++) {
    close[i].onclick = function() {
      var div = this.parentElement;
      div.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      min-width: 250px;
    }
    
    /* Include the padding and border in an element's total width and height */
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    /* Remove margins and padding from the list */
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    /* Style the list items */
    ul li {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: relative;
      padding: 12px 8px 12px 40px;
      list-style-type: none;
      background: #eee;
      font-size: 18px;
      transition: 0.2s;
      
      /* make the list items unselectable */
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
    }
    
    /* Set all odd list items to a different color (zebra-stripes) */
    ul li:nth-child(odd) {
      background: #f9f9f9;
    }
    
    /* Darker background-color on hover */
    ul li:hover {
      background: #ddd;
    }
    
    /* When clicked on, add a background color and strike out text */
    ul li.checked {
      background: #888;
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }
    
    /* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
    ul li.checked::before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      border-color: #fff;
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
      top: 10px;
      left: 16px;
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      height: 15px;
      width: 7px;
    }
    
    /* Style the close button */
    .close {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
    }
    
    .close:hover {
      background-color: #f44336;
      color: white;
    }
    
    /* Style the header */
    .header {
      background-color: #f44336;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    /* Clear floats after the header */
    .header:after {
      content: "";
      display: table;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    /* Style the input */
    input {
      margin: 0;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 0;
      width: 75%;
      padding: 10px;
      float: left;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    /* Style the "Add" button */
    .addBtn {
      padding: 10px;
      width: 25%;
      background: #d9d9d9;
      color: #555;
      float: left;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: 0.3s;
      border-radius: 0;
    }
    
    .addBtn:hover {
      background-color: #bbb;
    }
```

```html
<div id="myDIV" class="header">
      <h2 style="margin:5px">My To Do List</h2>
      <input type="text" id="myInput" placeholder="Title...">
      <span onclick="newElement()" class="addBtn">Add</span>
    </div>
    
    <ul id="myUL">
      <li>IR AL GYM</li>
      <li class="checked">PAGAR EL DIA DE HOY</li>
      <li>COMPRAR CEREAL</li>
     
    </ul>
```

El problema es entender la lógica para guardar los datos y me los deje en espera cuando no he seleccionado nada y, si ya seleccioné, que me los muestre tal cual con la palomita marcada.

Quiero crear un *insert* en *mysql* con *javascript* y quiero que en la *checklist* me aparecezca si se ha seleccionado un registro de la lista o no se ha seleccionado nada con *chekead*

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende por favor edita y organiza la estructura mejor

Comment: quiero crear un insert en mysql con js y quiero que la cheaklist me aparecesca si sea seleccionado un registro de la lista o no se a seleccionado nada con chekead

Comment: Entonces, lo que necesitas es guardar la lista de tareas, marcando las que ya se completaron, ¿cierto? Necesitas usar AJAX para enviar a PHP y poder guardar en base de datos, ¿has intentado algo?

Comment: el insert de php pero lo cambie para que sea js o ajax tal cual mas sencillo pero no encuentro la logica para hacer lo que mencionas

Comment: @RobertJosueMendoza ¿quieres guardar datos en MySQL usando JS? hasta donde yo sé eso es imposible o no (?). Saludos.

Comment: o de alguna forma adaptar esta cheaklist con mysql php